# Select key and return value OR select value and return key

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I imagine there is a very concise way to do this, but I'm new to .NET. I have a bunch of pairs for a mapping. The mapping works both ways though. I'd like to store them once, like this:

```
{"a", "a'"},
{"b", "b'"},
...
```

using a `Dictionary` or something. I know I can use linq to easily query a dictionary, but how can I conditionally have it return the key if I query a value or return the value if I input a key? For example, if input `b'`, output `b`. If input `a`, output `a'`.

The data structure does not have to be a dictionary by the way. I just want the most concise way to store it and the most concise way to retrieve it. This is not performance intensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dictionary extension method.

```
public static string Retrieve(this Dictionary<string,string> dictionary, string value)
    {
        var item = (from v in dictionary
                    where v.Key == value || v.Value == value
                    select (v.Key == value) ? v.Value : v.Key
                    ).FirstOrDefault();

        return item;
    }
```

Comment: the problem is that i dont know if it matched the key or the value. i have to know which it matched so i can return the corresponding value.

Answer (score 3):

The most concise way is the use a Dictionary and put everything in it, for example:

```
{ "a", "a'" }
{ "a'", "a" }
{ "b", "b'" }
{ "b'", "b" }
```

Lookup and usage would be fast and clear

Comment: i totally agree and this would be my general approach, but i was hoping c# would have something for this already.

Comment: @tau You could always create a wrapper class for `Dictionary<string, string>` which does this.

Comment: If you knew in advance that mostly you used the key for lookup but occasionally needed to look up by value you could use something like dict.Where(x=>x == "value").FirstOrDefault, but if you generally have to search the values it could be quite slow.